# ReactJS: image import problem with using api variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating weather card with openweather API and i want to use images like:

```
<img src={`${wicon}.png`} />
```

So, i have image named `'04d.png'` and `{wicon}` variable comes with `'04d'` code then i put `.png` at the end of the code but also i need to import image with name.How can i solve this problem? i also tried import image with `{wicon}` variable but doesnt work.
Note: the above code works like `'04d.png'` when i run the API and inspect the webpage but doesnt load.
Is there any method to use images without import like HTML?

EDIT: The problem solved when i uploaded the localserver and put `{wicon}` variable at the end of the localserver link.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYjg.png)

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the request is made for that image what is the server's response?

Comment: The browser will make a request for the image. The '04d.png' file needs to be in your `public` webserver folder.

Comment: @David something like this : [link](https://imgur.com/C67VyR9)

Comment: @Richard oh, so i cannot work in localserver?

Comment: @BatuhanCan: That shows the response as `text/html`.  The HTTP 304 code indicates that it's essentially [a cached response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304).  What's the actual content of the response?  What's the full URL of the request and what do you expect is the full URL of the image?

Comment: @David i have uploaded the response on [imgur](https://imgur.com/TH5GYFv) and something show up "This request has no response data available" on response tab.

Comment: @BatuhanCan: That looks like response headers, not the response content.  But if that is the actual content then that's definitely *text* and not an *image*.

Comment: @BatuhanCan: The point is... Your code is successfully building the value you expect and successfully making a request to your server.  As for where you image actually is or how to access it, we can't know.  But the code shown works, and the question asked is moot.

Comment: I will try to upload it to webserver i think there is no solution.